# Is there any solution for easy maintenance of Selenium automation scripts for testing Salesforce?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, salesforce, ui-automation, salesforce-lightning

Whenever there is salesforce upgrade, the Xpaths of lot of web elements get effected. This causes us to maintain them. Is there any better solution to this problem?

I have found a solution for input elements which are associated to an id. here is the link https://www.parasoft.com/blog/tips-tricks-for-testing-salesforce-enterprise-apps-with-selenium/

But the above solution solves it for only input elements, is there any other solution for reducing the maintenance efforts for button and fields to read the data as well?

Comment: Consider cross-posting to salesforce.stackexchange.com too. I've heard claims that "Provar" tests can survive a SF release in Lightning Experience. You'd have to evaluate yourself, maybe talk to sales... (I'm not affiliated in any way)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.